# Triggering a phone's multi-select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I'm working on a project that includes multi-select boxes on a mobile device. On mobile devices the default styling of multi-selects are very ugly. I want to do something similar to what is found with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) where you click on the link and it triggers the phone's multiselect box.  However, due to how jQuery Mobile takes over your site, using jQueryM isn't really an option.

Does anyone know how I can trigger the selection/focus/click/tap of the multiselect box on a phone? I've tried doing a label, click and focus function but haven't had any luck.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked firebug, on this particular page it's just a standard select menu with 0 opacity layered on top of the button. You -think- you're clicking the button, but it's actually a regular dropdown.

Comment: I was just going to post here that this was the answer. After looking through the jquery mobile code I'm kicking myself for not looking fully into the css.  Great simple solution.

Comment: Hey you're not alone - when I first saw the solution I thought there was no way it could be that simple